# HDFS Write Issue in Kerberos in Spark YARN Application

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos

I have a spark application, which reads data from Kafka and writes the data in HDFS. My application works fine for few minutes but after some time it starts giving below error and get failed.

```
2018-01-02 17:59:20 LeaseRenewer:username@nameservicename [WARN ] UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:username@REALM_NAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Clients credentials have been revoked (18))]
2018-01-02 17:59:20 Spark Context Cleaner [INFO ] ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 3480439
2018-01-02 17:59:20 LeaseRenewer:username@nameservicename [WARN ] Client - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Clients credentials have been revoked (18))]
2018-01-02 17:59:20 LeaseRenewer:username@nameservicename [WARN ] UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:username@REALM_NAME (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Clients credentials have been revoked (18))]
2018-01-02 17:59:20 Spark Context Cleaner [INFO ] ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 3480438
2018-01-02 17:59:20 LeaseRenewer:username@nameservicename [INFO ] RetryInvocationHandler - Exception while invoking renewLease of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB over namenode1/10.12.2.2:8020. Trying to fail over immediately.
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Clients credentials have been revoked (18))]; Host Details : local host is: "edgenode/10.12.2.1"; destination host is: "namenode1":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.renewLease(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.renewLease(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:590)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.renewLease(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Clients credentials have been revoked (18))]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    ... 16 more
```

Let me know if anyone know the resolution for this issue.

Comment: Is some initial data being written? Did you specify principal and key tab during startup? Or are you using the local ticket cache on the driver?

Comment: Yeah, for the few minutes or I can say 20 minutes it works fine and write data in hdfs but after that it starts giving above error and fails. My keytab and jaas login conf is locally available on each of the nodes and I am supplying principal and keytab during startup.

Comment: Are you using Ranger /sentry and the configuration of permissions changed in flight so access is no longer granted? Also did you experiment with the ticket from local ticket cache only I.e. Without specifying it then on spark submit? As an additional thing to try on small amount of test data use sparks local execution model for the job. Does this help?

Comment: I could not find _`Clients credentials have been revoked`_ in the list of standard Kerberos messages; that could be a specific Active Directory message, related to custom settings => check with your AD admins.

Comment: Also, do you inject distinct Kerberos settings for the Kafka consumer (via a JAAS conf file pointing to a keytab) and the standard Spark-to-Hadoop interface (via `--principal` / `--keytab`)? The Hadoop implementation of Kerberos *(based on the Java impl. but with several hacks and dirty tricks)* does not play well with the standard Java implementation of Kerberos...

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved. I was getting this issue because the **keytab** file was missing on one of the machine.